# Movement using quaternion

Tags: java, math, joml

I'm creating a first-person camera that rotates using Euler angles. I created the view matrix for the camera like this:

```
Quaternionf rotation = new Quaternionf().rotateXYZ(
  orientation.x,
  orientation.y,
  orientation.z
);

return new Matrix4f().rotate(rotation).translate(
  -this.position.x,
  -this.position.y,
  -this.position.z);
```

where orientation is a `Vector3f` of the Euler angles. How do I use the same rotation quaternion to move the camera position? And how do I get the view direction vector? I want to move the position of the camera from the view direction.

The math library I'm using is [JOML](https://joml-ci.github.io/JOML/), but it doesn't have a tag yet on StackOverflow.

Comment: What do you mean with "move the camera position"? The quaternion lets you perform a 3d rotation of some vector, whereas I understand "moving a position" to mean "a 3d translation", which doesn't involve quaternion maths.

Comment: Yeah but since I already have the quaternion can't I translate the position with respect to the view direction? Or is there some other way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the direction of the -Z axis when using the given `quaternion` (or likewise the given `matrix` with `matrix.rotate(quaternion)`) as the view transformation, then you can call either:

```java
Vector3f forward = quaternion.positiveZ(new Vector3f()).negate();
```

or

```java
Vector3f forward = matrix.positiveZ(new Vector3f()).negate();
```

Both of which will multiply the vector `(0, 0, 1)` to the right of the *inverted* quaternion/matrix and store the result into the supplied `Vector3f` instance.

This will give you the "forward" direction according to this view transformation in standard OpenGL right-handed view coordinate system.